# Moodle user enrollment from a CSV file

Tags: moodle

How to do bulk users enrollment from a CSV file to a Quiz inside moodle LMS?
and how to create groups and assign users from a CSV file to these groups?

Answer (score 0):

You can enrol users in a course (with the quiz setup inside the course) using the plugin "block csv enrol"
(sorry I cannot paste the link here due to stackoverflow limitations)

There are 2 kinds of groups in moodle course groups and global groups (cohorts), you can upload users to moodle with a csv file setting up cohorts for all of them as suggested here:

https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/Upload_cohorts#File_format_for_the_upload_cohorts_file

[This](https://docs.moodle.org/32/en/Cohorts#Creating_cohorts_in_bulk) is a sample csv file

Then you can create course internal groups automatically (based on the cohort setup) using the plugin "enrol groupsync"

Hope this is what you were looking for.